# How override styles in Ng-Bootstrap styles and edit html structure to Typeahead

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am using https://ng-bootstrap.github.io. I want to override the styles of the drop down with my styles, also change some css tags for the typeahead component, but cant seem to see where to do this?

**Code**:

```
<input id="sys_id" type="text" formControlName="sys_id" class="form-input" [ngbTypeahead]="search"/>
```

For example change the following:

```
<ngb-typeahead-window class="dropdown-menu show" role="listbox" id="ngb-typeahead-0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate(199px, 354px);"><!----><!--bindings={
 </ngb-typeahead-window>
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code and markup?

Comment: Its a dropdown menu, and thats the question where is this to edit and define?

Comment: You can find [an example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#template) that uses templates (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/amkypebybrl)). That would probably allow to style it as you like.

Comment: I have just looked at that, but how would that be implemented?

Comment: edit on code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding these 2 lines to **type-ahead-basic.ts** will style it

```
::ng-deep .dropdown-menu.show { background:lightblue;}
::ng-deep .dropdown-item { color:red !important; }
```

You can check a working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/vqlxvpqrvpk) - let me know if there is anything